# Chart not showing in TabBarView

Tags: flutter, dart

When i use a TabBarView i cannot show the page where it's showing api data inside chart:
[image]

It is showing the chart when its not inside TabBarView tho:
[image]

I can show dummy data from json example inside TabBarView but i want to show the data from the api which does not seem to work.

This is example of code when its not inside TabBarView. LineChartExample is the linechart widget which shows data from api.:

```
body: PageView(
          children: [
            LineChart1FromApi(),
          ],
        ),
```

The following example is code with TabBarView when it doesn't seem to get the api data and show the chart:

```
TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            PageView(
              children: [
                LineChart1FromApi(),
              ],
            ),
            PageView(
              children: [
                LineChart2FromApi(),
              ],
            ),
            PageView(
              children: [
                LineChart3FromApi(),
              ],
            ),
            PageView(
              children: [
                LineChart4FromApi(),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: Are you using `FutureBuilder` for api call on `LineChart2FromApi`?

Comment: Yes, but i also tried FutureBuilder with the LineChart1FromApi and it doesn't work either